# How to Duplicate last character using regex

Tags: regex

My question is how to duplicate last character of each line.

Example:

```
hello
hello2
hello$$
```

after replace

```
helloo
hello22
hello$$$
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is to duplicate the last character of each line of `yourfile`

```
sed 's/.$/&&/' yourfile
```

Comment: Please, downvoter, why is my answer worth a -1?